# Python OOP, cannot overwrite instances

Tags: python-3.x, oop, instances

I want to make 2 instances with same name like,

```
a = SomeClass(someAttr1) 
a = SomeClass(someAttr2)
```

so that the new one should overwrite the previous one.

I also tried this:

```
a = SomeClass(someAttr1) 
a = None
a = SomeClass(someAttr2)
```

I tried this but it doesn't overwrite the previous instance and adds it in itself, is there any way to do it?

Here is the code:

```
### Do not change the Location or Campus classes. ###
### Location class is the same as in lecture.     ###
class Location(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def move(self, deltaX, deltaY):
        return Location(self.x + deltaX, self.y + deltaY)

    def getX(self):
        return self.x

    def getY(self):
        return self.y

    def dist_from(self, other):
        xDist = self.x - other.x
        yDist = self.y - other.y
        return (xDist ** 2 + yDist ** 2) ** 0.5

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y)

    def __str__(self):
        return '<' + str(self.x) + ',' + str(self.y) + '>'


class Campus(object):
    def __init__(self, center_loc):
        self.center_loc = center_loc

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.center_loc)


class MITCampus(Campus):
    """ A MITCampus is a Campus that contains tents """
    tents_list = []
    def __init__(self, center_loc, tent_loc=Location(0, 0)):
        """ Assumes center_loc and tent_loc are Location objects
        Initializes a new Campus centered at location center_loc
        with a tent at location tent_loc """
        # Your code here
        Campus.__init__(self, center_loc)
        self.tent_loc = tent_loc
        self.tents_list.append(self.tent_loc)

    def add_tent(self, new_tent_loc):
        """ Assumes new_tent_loc is a Location
        Adds new_tent_loc to the campus only if the tent is at least 0.5 distance
        away from all other tents already there. Campus is unchanged otherwise.
        Returns True if it could add the tent, False otherwise. """
        # Your code here

        new_tent_flag = True
        for loc in self.tents_list:
            if loc == new_tent_loc or new_tent_loc.dist_from(loc) < 0.5:
                new_tent_flag = False

        if new_tent_flag:
            self.tents_list.append(new_tent_loc)
            return True
        else:
            return False


    def get_tents(self):
        """ Returns a list of all tents on the campus. The list should contain
        the string representation of the Location of a tent. The list should
        be sorted by the x coordinate of the location. """
        # Your code here
        new_list_sorted = sorted(self.tents_list, key=lambda tent: tent.getX())
        str_list = []
        for x in new_list_sorted:
            str_list.append(x.__str__())

        return str_list
```

Test Cases:

```
Test: 0


        c = MITCampus(Location(1,2))
        print(c.add_tent(Location(1,2)))
        print(c.add_tent(Location(0,0)))
        print(c.add_tent(Location(2,3)))
        print(c.add_tent(Location(2,3)))
        print(c.get_tents())


Output:

    True
    False
    True
    False
    ['<0,0>', '<1,2>', '<2,3>']

Test: 1


        init campus with default tent loc
        c = MITCampus(Location(-1,-2))
        print(sorted(c.get_tents()))


Output:

    ['<0,0>','<0,0>', '<1,2>', '<2,3>']

Expected Output:

        ['<0,0>']
```

As can be seen that the second instance should overwrite the previous one but instead it is adding it. Is the problem in the code? and how to solve it?

Comment: please create a [mcve]. "doesn't overwrite" is very vague. Why do you think the old object isn't being overwritten?

Comment: I'm not sure why you deleted the calls but now the question doesn't make any sense.. You should create a minimal example of your code instead of deleting the whole thing.

Comment: i deleted code as it was assignment and i'm not sure that i am allowed to put it here and also it destroys the purpose of assignment.
but yeah i will update it in a better way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,
Your `tents_list` attribute is a class atribute, so even when your `c` object is overwrited the `tents_list` attribute stays the same.
It's better to make your tents_list an object argument so the `tents_list` attribute is overwrited too.

```
def __init__(self, center_loc, tent_loc=Location(0, 0)):
    Campus.__init__(self, center_loc)
    self.tents_list = []  # <--- Add this
    self.tent_loc = tent_loc
    self.tents_list.append(self.tent_loc)
```

Comment: you should update your previous answer instead of generating another one

Comment: this worked fine, thanks, but there is only one error, should i update the post regarding that?

Comment: Depends, if the new error is closely related edit your question, else post a new question

Answer (score 0):

The object is overwritten but you defined `tents_list` as a class variable so all of the instances of `MITCampus` **share** this list.
So any new instance will add to that list and that seems to you as not "overwritten".

If you want that "overwriting" behavior, move the `tents_list` into the `__init__` method as `self.tents_list`. Only then it will be unique for each instance.